# Cheat not working?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I was playing Gta 5 on Xbox360 and I used the bang bang explosive bullets thing and I know I put it in correctly and all of the other cheats worked except this one. Can someone please tell me if this cheat does not work?

Comment: I could be wrong but i believe cheat related questions are not of the criteria from Arqade.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Cheats are fine, so long as it's not multiplayer cheating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This cheat does work, you might be entering it incorrectly.

Remember:

> RB = Right bumper
>
> LB = Left bumper
>
> RT = Right trigger

This is the code.

> RIGHT, X, A, LEFT, RB, RT, LEFT, RIGHT, RIGHT, LB, LB, LB.